# PHP retrieve youtube video information

Tags: php, video, youtube

I have tried multiple times to get a quick PHP function for retrieving youtube video info (title, duration etc..) Here's my latest revision:

```
function YTInfo($YTID){
if(($json_output = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://youtube.com/watch?v='.$YTID.'&format=json'))){ 
    return json_decode($json_output, true); 
}else{ 
    return false; 
}
}
```

Like my previous attempts, it works but it's too slow. A class I found online took 1,5-2 seconds to retrieve the info of ten videos. My first version using cURL took about a second and the code above takes about half a second. I need it to execute faster though.

**Update: issue resolved.**
It turns out that the YouTube oEmbed request time was the bottle neck here, This is about as quick as I'll be able to get it.

Comment: Consider checking if the loading time is due long server request (youtube) [there's nothing you can do to improve it] or on your side - the parsing process.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that the request time is about 40-60ms so I won't be able to make it any quicker.